# Replace period following a digit

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I've come across a problem that seems simple, yet solution I've found isn't satisfying. I want to replace any period followed by a number with a comma. For example,

```
strings <- c("22.222.222", "12.323", "don.t replace")
```

would be successfully transformed as

```
[1] "22,222,222"    "12,323"        "don.t replace"
```

The first solution I attempted was

```
str_replace_all(strings,
                "(?<=\\d+)\\.",
                ",")
```

but I got the following error message:

```
Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, replacement, vectorize_all = vec,  : 
 Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)
```

When I use

```
str_replace_all(strings,
            "(?<=\\d{1,3})\\.",
            ",")
```

I get the correct transformation. However, the hard-coded 1-3 digits is not what I want and I don't understand why `\\d+` doesn't work but `\\d{1,3}` does.

Comment: Isn't `"(?<=\\d)\\."` good enough?

Comment: Why do you need a lookahead? I mean you accepted an answer with a lookahead solution, and it is really not what you need here. Lookbehinds are costly in terms of performance (at least when placed at the start of the pattern), and you should avoid them whenever possible. Note that lookbehinds that restrict an already consumed substring are efficient, but it is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the `+` quantifier, all you care about is matching the last digit in the sequence. So just put `\d` in the lookbehind.

```
str_replace_all(strings,
                "(?<=\\d)\\.",
                ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any lookarounds here since the digits are a known subpattern and you do not need any overlapping matches. Just  use a capturing group around the digits and restore them in the result with the backreference:

```
> library(stringr)
> strings <- c("22.222.222", "12.323", "don.t replace")
> str_replace_all(strings, "(\\d+)\\.", "\\1,")
[1] "22,222,222"    "12,323"        "don.t replace"
```

Or with the base R `gsub`:

```
> gsub("(\\d+)\\.", "\\1,", strings)
[1] "22,222,222"    "12,323"        "don.t replace"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI1cR9/1)

Note that `(?<=\\d{1,3})` *constrained-width* look-behind works because *stringr* regex flavor is [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). It will work if the pattern length in the lookbehind can be calculated beforehand, so the limiting quantifier with both min and max values works OK. It will not work with PCRE (`perl=T`) regexps with `gsub`. Infinite-width lookbehind (with `+` and `*` quantifiers inside) is only supported in few flavors: Python PyPi regex module,  .NET, RegexBuddy tool, Vim.