# Replacing commas to periods in all colums in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function to change the numbers in a column so that the ',' is a '.'

I want to then convert that column into a double.

For example, here is some data to copy/paste:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("1,1", "2,2"))
```

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854776/replace-period-following-a-digit)? You're just going in the other direction...

Comment: the source is CSV. i need to write a function as this is for an assignment.

Comment: What is the source of your data? It sounds like you are getting it from a source where decimal points are represented by commas. If you read the `read.table/read.csv` function manual page, you will see that there is an argument that will handle the conversion for you.

Comment: I need to write a function. Not sure how it'll look. How do i write a function that can do that and utilize as.double and gsub?

Answer (score 0):

First do some pattern matching and replacement with `gsub`, then coerce the column to class `double`.

```
df   <- data.frame(a=c("1,1", "2,2"))
df$b <- as.double(gsub(",", ".", df$a))
df
    a   b
1 1,1 1.1
2 2,2 2.2
```

To make this a function:

```
my_function <- function(x) {
  as.double(gsub(",", ".", x))
}
my_function(df$a)
[1] 1.1 2.2
```

Comment: what do i replace a with and "1,1" or "2.2"

Comment: It's changing when i print but not in the actual sheet. I need it to change in the actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are in csv format, just read in the file with the decimal set to a comma:

```
read.csv("my_file.csv", dec = ",")
```

No function needed. Checkout `?read.table` for details.